# Error with lists in Java

Tags: java, list, collections

For some reason:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
```

gives me an error (red line) under the word List, but this:

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
```

doesn't.

Why is that?

Comment: Have you imported `java.util.List`?

Comment: I don't believe you. What does the error say?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't import `java.awt.List` by accident instead?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized and does not contain error description

Answer (score 3):

You should import `java.util.List`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2  `List` classes called  in Java.

1. [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
2. [java.awt.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/List.html).

Make sure you are not mixing them. 
OR  u can Use.

```
java.util.List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
```